# Open API Server - openapi-generator with spring boot 3

Tags: openapi-generator, spring-boot-3

I search for informations and clarifications about using openapi-generator with spring boot 3.
As I see in [samples](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/samples/openapi3/server/petstore/springboot-3), there is no declaration of this code:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${openapi-generator.version}</version>
            <executions>
             ...
            </executions>
       </plugin>
```

Meanwhile I see this config `useSpringBoot3`.

My question: the plugin is no more used with spring boot 3 ?

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useSpringBoot3` configuration in the plugin configuration like below:

```
<configOptions>
        <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
</configOptions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you're not the first person to run into this trap, but the "samples" section in the repository contains samples of generated code, not samples of configurations for the code generator.  You cannot look at the `pom` there and expect it to provide answers for you.  The closest you can find to a pom example is [the one in the tests](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/src/test/resources/default/pom.xml).  However, even that example is pretty useless.

The `openapi generator` has a bit of a learning curve, but the documentation is pretty helpful.  For example, the documentation for the `maven plugin` provides a complete list of [configuration properties](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin#general-configuration-parameters), and the Spring generator has even more [config options](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md#config-options).  You can reference these options, as well as numerous other examples in stack overflow such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73461247/spring-boot-openapi-generator-plugin-creates-unwanted-test-file), or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69677405/how-can-i-compile-a-project-that-implements-interfaces-in-generated-sources-fold).  [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369664/how-openapi-generator-openapi-generator-ignore-works-on-openapi-generator-maven/76369775#76369775) even uses the `useSpringBoot3` option.  [Here's a search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openapi-generator%20spring-boot%20maven?sort=MostVotes&uqlId=72144&edited=true) link that is filtered down to help you find a lot more examples.

The github issues section is also another great place to find examples from other people.